# Javascript RegExp Validation

Tags: javascript, regex, validation

Help, I need a regexp validation that checks alphanumeric (A-Z or a-z and 0-9) with some special character (@#$%&) which is optional, but the length must be 8 to 15 characters

For example,

```
training = false
training1 = true
@training1 = true
@training = false
tr@ining1 = true (Position doesn't matter)
```

I have this, but it only validate the alphanumeric in the length of 8 to 15 characters

```
(?=.*[A-Za-z])(?=.*[0-9]){8,15}
```

How do I include the optional checking for the specific characters?

Comment: `training` is 8 characters, `@training` is nine characters. Why should these fail?

Comment: My requirement is it must be in alphanumeric. @training is not alphanumeric. Special character is optional in this case but only those specific one.

Comment: @user2435677  is this /^(?![a-z]+$)(?![a-z@#$%&]+$)(?!\d+$)(?![\d@#$%&]+$)[a-z\d@#$%&]{8,15}$/i   what you want?

Comment: Total length must be in 8 to 15 characters include those special characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well,I think you can try:

```
/^(?![a-z]+$)(?![a-z@#$%&]+$)(?!\d+$)(?![\d@#$%&]+$)[a-z\d@#$%&]{8,15}$/i
```

**Match result:**

```
training = false
training1 = true
@training1 = true
@training = false
tr@ining1 = true  
12345678 = false
12345678a = true
@12345678 = false
```

Comment: I tried 12345678 it gives false is correct. However, I tried 12345678a should give me a true response. But I get a false.

Comment: Code like this? 
var a = new RegExp('^(?![a-z]+$)(?![a-z@#$%&]+$)(?!\d+$)(?![\d@#$%&]+$)[a-z\d@#$%&]{8,15}$');

Comment: @user2435677  code like this:  var a=/^(?![a-z]+$)(?![a-z@#$%&]+$)(?!\d+$)(?![\d@#$%&]+$)[a-z\d@#$%&]{8,15}$/i;